# cannot instantiate an Xception model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm running Keras in an NVIDIA Docker container on a multi-GPU machine. I'd like to instantiate a fairly standard model (Xception), but I keep getting weird errors. MRE:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import Xception

height = 299
width = 299
num_classes = 1000

# Instantiate model
model = Xception(weights=None, input_shape=(height, width, 3), classes=num_classes)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = Xception(weights=None, input_shape=(height, width, 3), classes=num_classes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/xception.py", line 235, in Xception
    x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 881, in call
    output = self.activation(output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/activations.py", line 29, in softmax
    return K.softmax(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2963, in softmax
    return tf.nn.softmax(x, axis=axis)
TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Versions for Python, Keras & Tensorflow:

```
python -c 'import keras; import tensorflow; import sys; print(sys.version, 'keras.__version__', 'tensorflow.__version__')'
Using TensorFlow backend.
('2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]', '2.1.6', '1.4.0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems its a known issue with keras and tensorflow `1.4` version as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9621). You may want to update both to the latest version to resolve this issue.

Comment: You mean upgrading `tensorflow`: `keras` is already the latest release. Right?