# Cannot use ModelCheckpoint with MobileNet in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a MobileNet on dummy data in Keras, in a Docker container on a multi-GPU machine. [Initially I was trying to train Xception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630821/cannot-instantiate-an-xception-model-in-keras), but I decided to switch to a smaller  model, so that even people with a less powerful machine can replicate my code. I get some conflicts with `ModelCheckpoint` which I cannot understand.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.utils
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import os


height = 224
width = 224
channels = 3
epochs = 10
num_classes = 10

# Generate dummy data
batch_size = 32  
n_train = 256
n_test = 64
x_train = np.random.random((n_train, height, width, channels))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(num_classes, size=(n_train, 1)), num_classes=num_classes)
x_test = np.random.random((n_train, height, width, channels))
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(num_classes, size=(n_test, 1)), num_classes=num_classes)
# Get input shape
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]

# Instantiate model 
model = MobileNet(weights=None,
                  input_shape=input_shape,
                  classes=num_classes)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Viewing Model Configuration
model.summary()

# Model file name
filepath = 'model_epoch_{epoch:02d}_loss_{loss:0.2f}_val_{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'

# Define save_best_only checkpointer
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath,
                             monitor='val_acc',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True)

# Let's fit!
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "very_basic_test.py", line 52, in <module>
    callbacks=[checkpointer])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1490, in _standardize_user_data
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 220, in _check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 256 input samples and 64 target samples.
```

Python, Keras and Tensorflow versions:

```
python -c 'import keras; import tensorflow; import sys; print(sys.version, 'keras.__version__', 'tensorflow.__version__')'
Using TensorFlow backend.
('2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]', '2.1.6', '1.7.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to the checkpoint callback but rather the data you are providing. Have a look at `x_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` to check for a mismatch in the number of samples, size of first dimension. The error seems to occur on that line because that is the call of the `.fit` function.

Comment: you're right, `x_train` had the wrong shape. How did you understand? In the error message, I'm not sure what `input samples` and `target samples` are.

Comment: They are exactly x_train and y_train respectively, input = x, target = y.